# Delete objects in Array if there is a similar string

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to remove the last item of a few different arrays if there is already a title that is created with the same name..

1. I check if the array is > 1. So that it doesn't delete the first item added. Or if theres only 1 item.
2. I then check if the array contains the last item added. I subtract one from the size to get the last item.
3. I remove all of the last items from the arrays.

   - Note : All of my arrays are equivalent in size which is why I use the same int for remove.

The problem is that it does not remove them if it contains the last String value added.

```
if(titleTextArrayList.size() > 1) {
    if (Arrays.asList(titleTextArrayList)
            .contains(titleTextArrayList
                .get(titleTextArrayList.size() - 1))) {

        titleTextArrayList.remove(titleTextArrayList.size() - 1);
        notesArrayList.remove(titleTextArrayList.size() - 1);

        ll.removeView(checkBoxArrayList.get(titleTextArrayList.size() - 1));
        checkBoxArrayList.remove(titleTextArrayList.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you use Set class for this purpose? As far as i understood your need, Set is suitable for you.

Comment: I'm completely confused. What does `if (Arrays.asList(titleTextArrayList).contains(titleTextArrayList.get(titleTextArrayList.size()-1)))` mean? `Arrays.asList` takes an array, but an array doesn't have a `size` method.

Comment: checking if Arrays.asList(MyList).contains(String value)...Basically checking the last value of the array to everything else inside the array.

Comment: @cppbeginner I think it's a very convoluted way of writing `if (false)`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Look at it again. The OP is passing a list to Arrays.asList. It only compiles at all because Arrays.asList is a hideous varargs method.

Comment: I dont want it to delete the last item if its false...

Comment: @cppbeginner yes. It is checking if a list of list of whatevers contains the last element in a list of whatevers, I.e. a whatever. Since a whatever isn't a list of whatevers, this will always be false.

Comment: It could be true if the last element of the list is a reference to the list itself. Clearly not what the OP intended.

Comment: Right I intend to check if the last element is equal to any item in the list. -exact string comparison.

Comment: @AndyTurner `List<Object> foo = Arrays.asList(1); foo.set(0, foo); System.out.println(Arrays.asList(foo).contains(foo.get(foo.size() - 1)));
    `

Comment: @pewpew Sorry my comments are not really helping. I suggest you include more code (including variable declarations) and expand a bit on what you are trying to do. What you have written really doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @cppbeginner ok, I see. In that circumstance, it might not be false. In that case it's a convoluted way of writing `list.contains(list)`.

Comment: Yeah I'm working on it. Thanks Ill update here if I figure it out.

Comment: @AndyTurner It's very odd whatever it means and shouldn't compile. I think Josh Bloch says in Effective Java that making Arrays.asList a varargs method was a mistake.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I want to smack myself... I had

```
titleTextArrayList.remove(titleTextArrayList.size()-1)
```

before everything else which basically meant i was deleting the last element in the array before i had a chance to delete everything else... So I put that at the end. Made the code a little bit easier to read.

```
private void datacheck(String data) {

        if(titleTextArrayList.size() > 1) {

            for (int i = 0; i < titleTextArrayList.size()-1; i++) {

                    if (titleTextArrayList.get(i).equals(data))
                        {
                            Log.i("ArraySize = ",Integer.toString(titleTextArrayList.size()-1));
                            Log.i("I Value = ",Integer.toString(i));

                        notesArrayList.remove(titleTextArrayList.size()-1);
                        ll.removeView(checkBoxArrayList.get(titleTextArrayList.size()-1));
                        checkBoxArrayList.remove(titleTextArrayList.size()-1);
                        titleTextArrayList.remove(titleTextArrayList.size()-1);

                    }

            }
        }
    }
```